# Can "onClick" events in HTML pages change variables on a JS page?

Tags: jquery, scope, onclick, switch-statement

I have 3 buttons on an HTML page and I want them each to change a variable, defined in my scripts.js, to a designated variable when they are clicked. The variable will then trigger a switch statement that depends on the string the variable contains and open a popup video.

I have tried just adding a function that takes a string as a parameter and then the function reassigns the global variable and then adding the function to an `onClick` event, but the variable is never updated when the buttons are clicked.

Here are my buttons in the HTML page:

```
<button onclick="get_doctor_ID('agrawal')" type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-3 px-4 open-agrawal">Learn More</button>

<button onclick="get_doctor_ID('looney')" type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-3 px-4 open-looney">Learn More</button>

<button onclick="get_doctor_ID('cheeks')" class="btn btn-danger mt-3 px-4 open-cheeks">Learn More</button>
```

Here is my JS:

```
var doctorID = 'test'

function get_doctor_ID(ID) {

    doctorID = ID;

}

switch (doctorID) {

    case 'test':

        alert("The statement is working!");

        break;

    case 'index':

        alert("Index Video has been selected!");

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.open').click(function() {
                $('.pop-outer').fadeIn('slow')
            })
            $('.closeBackground').click(function() {
                $('.pop-outer').fadeOut('slow');
            })
        });

        break;

    case 'agrawal':

        alert("Agrawal Video has been selected!");

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.open-agrawal').click(function() {
                $('.pop-outer').fadeIn('slow')
            })
            $('.closeBackground-agrawal').click(function() {
                $('.pop-outer').fadeOut('slow');
            })
        });

        break;

    case 'looney':

        alert("Looney Video has been selected!");

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.open-looney').click(function() {
                $('.pop-outer').fadeIn('slow')
            })
            $('.closeBackground-looney').click(function() {
                $('.pop-outer').fadeOut('slow');
            })
        });

        break;

    case 'cheeks':

        alert("Cheeks Video has been selected!");

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.open-cheeks').click(function() {
                $('.pop-outer').fadeIn('slow')
            })
            $('.closeBackground-cheeks').click(function() {
                $('.pop-outer').fadeOut('slow');
            })
        });

        break;
}
```

I expect that when a button is clicked, the function will run and change the `doctorID` variable, then the switch statement will display the proper pop-out. However, it seems that either the variable never changes, or does change, but doesn't trigger the switch statement.

Comment: The switch statement is not inside a function.  How is it expected to rerun?

Comment: Since the switch statement isn't in the function, it just runs once when the page is first loaded, and never runs again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed up your JavaScript a little to use some more JQuery. I wrapped everything in a `document.ready()` and removed your `onclick` functions from your buttons to just have a JQuery `.on` 'click' selector on the id's of the buttons.

Check out this jsfiddle to see if this is what you're looking for in terms of functionality: https://jsfiddle.net/738wnzjk/1/

Hopefully this should get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There simply is a `}` wrong in place, which **closes the function before the switch-statement**.
Change it like this:

```
function get_doctor_ID(ID) {

    doctorID = ID;

} // <-- remove this
```

The proper closing braket for the function after the switch is already in place, I see. so simply delete that bracket.

Comment: It's not as simple as that.  The logic of the switch is creating event bindings.  As is, re-executing the switch statement is not going to unbind previously created bindings